# How to make the change take effect immediately after changing a js file?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, myeclipse

I am editing a JavaScript file in MyEclipse.

When I try to change some content, I currently have to restart Tomcat.

If I don't, the change will not take effect.

By the way, I am using Chrome.

Is there a good way to make my changes take effect immediately without restarting Tomcat?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy your JavaScript file into the deployment directory when you're done editing it.

The deployment directory is where Tomcat places your files when it builds and deploys.

I don't know exactly where it is for Tomcat, but it should be pretty easy to determine.

I typically use a little shell script to make this more convenient.